# How to refer to "\" sign in python string

Tags: python, string

I have problem with refering to special symbol in string:

I have: `path='C:\dir\dir1\dir2\filename.doc'`

and I want `filename`.

When I try: `filename=path[path.rfind("\"):-4]`

then interpreter says it's an error line right from "\" since is treated as a comment.

Comment: Please read the documentation.  http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals  Says `\\\`

Comment: You might want to try to avoid putting literal paths in your script; by taking the filenames from other sources (command line, basic config file, etc.) you can avoid this whole problem. Makes your code more reusable too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `"\\"`, technically it would be better to use `os.path.sep` if you insist on using backslashes. But better yet, use `/` in your paths, it works fine on Windows

Python has [builtin functions to manipulate paths](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html). Note that you need to double the backslashes if you still prefer them to forwardslashes

```
>>> import os
>>> path='C:\\dir\\dir1\\dir2\\filename.doc'
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))
('filename', '.doc')
```

and using forwardslashes

```
>>> path='C:/dir/dir1/dir2/filename.doc'
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))
('filename', '.doc')
```

Comment: +1 for pointing to the already-working and also portable standard implementation.

Comment: +1: Very nice answer.  Forgot this, though: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 2):

Either escape it as "\\" or use raw strings like so: r"\".

Comment: @Gnibbler: `path = r'C:\dir\dir1\dir2\filename.doc'` works. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @Manoj: @Gnibbler is right, `r"\"` does not work (and neither does `r'C:\dir\dir1\dir2\'`), because even in raw strings, `\'`/`\"` still escapes (it has to)

Answer (score 1):

Escape it:

```
filename=path[path.rfind("\\"):-4]
```

or better yet, use [`basename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) - part of Python's [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) library:

```
from os.path import basename
basename(path)
```

From the manual for `basename`:

> Return the base name of pathname path. This is the second half of the pair returned by `split(path)`. Note that the result of this function is different from the Unix basename program; where basename for `'/foo/bar/'` returns `'bar'`, the `basename()` function returns an empty string (`''`).

Answer (score 0):

You can type double the : "\".

However to split the filename out of Windows filename, use partition as os.path.split only works with /:

```
>>> path=r'C:\dir\dir1\dir2\filename.doc'
>>> print path.rpartition('\\')[-1]
filename.doc
```

Comment: Noticed it while playing with the IDLE and edited 10 minutes before your comment. Same time as I put in the rpartition code. Maybe \ is not working for me for os.path.split as I am now running Linux. I think it and basename should work.

Comment: Edited 10 minutes _after_ my comment :)

Comment: Damn this screen resolution. Mixed it up. But without purpose. I read your comment only after correcting my post. I only learned it through my testing, so thanks for sharing your knowledge (or is it painful memories ;) )

Answer (score 0):

There is something about this in the FAQ: [Why can’t raw strings (r-strings) end with a backslash?](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html?highlight=raw%20string#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash)

> If you’re trying to build Windows
>   pathnames, note that all Windows
>   system calls accept forward slashes
>   too:
>
> ```
> f = open("/mydir/file.txt")  # works fine!
> ```
>
> If you’re trying to build a pathname
>   for a DOS command, try e.g. one of
>
> ```
> dir = r"\this\is\my\dos\dir" "\\"
> dir = r"\this\is\my\dos\dir\ "[:-1] 
> dir = "\\this\\is\\my\\dos\\dir"
> ```