# I want to remove '\' from a string in python

Tags: python, controls, character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to refer to “\” sign in python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531430/how-to-refer-to-sign-in-python-string)

I've quite large string data in which I've to remove all characters other than A-Z,a-z and 0-9
I'm able to remove almost every character but '\' is a problem.

every other character is removed but '\' is making problem

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

reps = {' ':'-','.':'-','"':'-',',':'-','/':'-',
        '<':'-',';':'-',':':'-','*':'-','+':'-',
        '=':'-','_':'-','?':'-','%':'-','!':'-',
        '$':'-','(':'-',')':'-','\#':'-','[':'-',
        ']':'-','\&':'-','@':'-','\W':'-','\t':'-'}

x.name = x.name.lower()

x1 = replace_all(x.name,reps)
```

Comment: You probably need to escape the string, with "\\".

Comment: I'm not able to get rid of '\' character, how can i do it using above code?? Thank you very very much for your reply :)

Comment: Are you aware that by only allowing a-z you are excluding some letters from other alphabets such as å? Is this really what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string:

```
a = 'hi how \\are you'
```

you can remove it by doing:

```
a.replace('\\','')

>'hi how are you'
```

If you have a specific context where you are having trouble, I recommend posting a bit more detail.

Comment: actually I'm working on thepiratebay data dump in which attributes are separated by '|'. I'm making an indexer for it. In names of torrents, I need only text, no symbols or control words

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track. Escaping the \ will allow you to include that in your dictionary. You could probably make the code a bit more elegant with a short lambda function and a regex rather than a big dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

> I've quite large string data in which I've to remove all characters other than A-Z,a-z and 0-9

In other words, you want to keep only those characters.

The string class already provides a test "is every character a letter or number?", called `.isalnum()`. So, we can just `filter` with that:

```
>>> filter(str.isalnum, 'foo-bar\\baz42')
'foobarbaz42'
```

Comment: This won't work. `filter(str.isalnum, 'foo-bar\\bazå42')` gives `'foobarbaz\xe542'`

Comment: is there any library needed for this function ?

Comment: @kindall: Yes, å is alphabetic and therefore alphanumeric. However alphabetically å comes *after* z. The OP specifically asked only for a-z. Because å isn't in the range a-z it should be excluded, but this solution does not exclude it. Either the question is wrong, or the answer is.

Comment: `isalnum` is unicode aware, so it can treat more than just regular ascii as being alphanumeric (according to locale).

Comment: No library is needed. It is built-in.

Answer (score 1):

birryee is correct, you need to escape the backslash with a second backslash.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be better to vote up the post, rather than add another answer?

Comment: @Darthfett: He didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @MarkByers Thanks, I apologize for not looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

> to remove all characters other than A-Z, a-z and 0-9

Instead of trying to list all the characters you want to remove (that would take a *long* time), use a regular expression to specify those characters you wish to keep:

```
import re
text = re.sub('[^0-9A-Za-z]', '-', text)
```